# Filtering data after fetching in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to make a list of objects based on combined data from 2 arrays, one comes from a localStorage and the second one from Django backend. First of all objects from localStorage are displayed by `showCart()` function

```
export const showCart = () => {
    if (typeof window !== undefined) {
        if (localStorage.getItem("cart")) {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
        };
    };
};
```

it returns data in this format: FE: `{ id: 1, amount: 7, size: "L", product: 1 }`. `product` is the Foreign Key needed to match data from other array.

The second array comes form a backend and it is feched by `getAllProducts()` function

```
export const getAllProducts = () => {
    return fetch(`${url}/products/`, {method: "GET"})
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
};
```

It returns data in this format: FE `{ name: "Red", id: 3, price: 33, image:"some-url"}`
​​

Now I need to create another list of objects by merging then by `product` of an object in first array with `id` of an object from the second one. The objects in the third array need to contain `amount` and `size` from first array as well as `name`, `price` and `image` from the second one. In the end I want to store it in `useState()`.

This is what I came up with, I guess my code stops working arter first for loop:

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

   const CheckAnonymousCart = () => {
        getAllProducts()
        .then((data) => {
            const localCart = showCart();
            var products = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < localCart.lenght; i++) {
                for (let y = 0; y < data.lenght; y++) {
                    if (localCart[i].product === data[y].id) {
                        console.log(localCart[i].product, data[y].id)
                        const item = {
                            name: data[y].name,
                            price: data[y].price,
                            image: data[y].image,
                            amount: localCart[i].amount,
                            size: localCart[i].size,
                        }
                        products.push(item)
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            setCart(products);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    };
```

​​Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you checked if this is your problem? There is a typo in the for loop conditions: `for (let i = 0; i < localCart.lenght; i++)`

Comment: I can't see any typo

Comment: `data.lenght` should be `data.length` (`lenght` appears in a few places)

Comment: Yes it was just a typo everything works fine now thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Jacob's comment, you probably want to avoid `FETCH`'ing all products from the DB, because it requires more DB resources, most of the info is not required, and it makes the for-loop take longer to `JOIN` both lists.

Ideally, you would use a parameterized query like so:

```
return fetch(`${url}/products/?id=1&id=2&id=3`, {method: "GET"})
```

Where `?id=1&id=2&id=3` are a subset of the product IDs that you're retrieving.

**Note:** You will also want to sanitize/validate the product IDs in `localStorage`, because the data can be modified by the end-user, which is a potential attack vector by malicious users.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could simply be the typo from the for loop conditions, but you can also accomplish this more succinctly using the JS ES6 methods:

```js
const products = localCart.map(item => {
    const match = data.find(x => x.id === item.product);
    return {
        amount,
        size,
        name: match?.name,
        price: match?.price,
        image: match?.image
    }
});
```